# Creating Nuget packages for .Net Core class libraries, "The dependency does not support framework .NetStandard version 1.6"

Tags: nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

I've been trying to create NuGet package for a class library I wrote (.Net Core). I'm doing this through appending this to my `Project.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
   "postcompile": [
      "dotnet pack --no-build --configuration %compile:Configuration%"
   ]
},
```

However, when I install the package, I get the following error: 
[image]

I face the same problem when doing this manually using `NuGet.exe` through `spec` and `pack` commands.

Comment: Are there any dependencies of this library?

Comment: Can you show the whole project.json of ExtendedWeb?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that this ExtendedWeb dependency is built to target .NET Standard 1.6 or higher. It is possible that it does not yet support .NET Standard.

Comment: I have already made sure about that before posting the question. But whatever I try I get the same error.

Comment: Is ExtendedWeb something publicly available that I can check?